# How to implement Log4net for my Asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to Implement Logging future using log4net for my asp.net mvc application..

Can any body has the Sample project so that I can take a look? and where do i need to find out the dll's for log4net?

Thanks

I Used this link to implement Loging for my application
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/log4net.aspx

How do I need to log this error to my database table? what do I need to write in my Class? to store the values in the table
thanks

Comment: "where do i need to find out the dll's for log4net" Really? http://www.google.com/search?q=log4net doesn't help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get it [from here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html.).

Here are [some examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html).

Comment: thanks Driss, I need to log the Errors to the database table?

Comment: Please take some time to study the documentation. Configuring for MS SQL Server is almost at the top here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Comment: The correct download link is http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html (without the trailing period)

Answer (score 2):

Well to be honest you hardly made an effort if you couldn't find the DLLs, which are available [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html).

You will want to add the DLL as a reference in your project and then follow the directions [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

This guide might help you:
http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/07/ConfiguringLog4NetForWebApplications.aspx

You can download the source code and the DLLs from here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html